# How to transfer a variable value from one bot task to another bot task in Workfusion RPA Express?

Tags: business-process-management, rpa, workfusion

I am trying to design a business process that will take the variable value from the first bot task and use it again in the subsequent bot tasks. Can anyone please tell me how to do that in RPA Express?

Answer (score 4):

Set the data you need in the first task, then reference the data by using the same variable name.

First task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config charset="UTF-8">    
   <export include-original-data="true">
      <single-column name="city" value="london" />
   </export>
</config>
```

Second task:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <config xmlns="http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/schema/1.0/config"
      scriptlang="groovy">
      <script><![CDATA[
         log.info(city.toString())
      ]]></script>  
      <export include-original-data="false">
      </export>
  </config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same variable name in both bot tasks. In this case the value will be automatically passed from one task to the other.